# Is Protractor with waitForAngularEnabled(false) as good as using selenium webdriver?

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have an angular website that I need to automate. I planned to use Protractor but due to something in the app ( not sure if polling, keepAlive or something else ), protractor tests timeouts at the very first element and doesn't find it. But if I use `waitforangularenabled(false)`, then it works fine. But I have to use await with almost every statement.

Now, I wonder if its as good as using selenium in Java in this scenario. Any thoughts?

Comment: Protractor build upon selenium,  `waitforangularenabled()` is wrapped by protractor, selenium not supply any build-in feature which is equivalent to ``waitforangularenabled()`.  For selenium, it treats any page evenly,  it doesn't care the page developed by angular, JSP+ Java, C# or other tech stack.

Answer (score 2):

`If set to false, Protractor will not wait for Angular $http and $timeout tasks to complete before interacting with the browser. This can cause flaky tests, but should be used if, for instance, your app continuously polls an API with $timeout.`

This is from the official documentation for `waitforangularenabled` from the Protractor documentation.

`But if I use waitforangularenabled(false), then it works fine.` -so, if you're facing this issue where the tests timeouts without using this flag, then it means in the background there is some digest cycle running which is preventing Protractor to consider the page to be stable enough to test.

`I have to use await with almost every statement.` - this is recommended but not compulsory. Please see the documentation again which tells about this. If you set the promise manager flag ( `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER`) to `false`, then only it will not use the Promise manager. If you're using Jasmine with Protractor, then use can use Protractor without using `async/await`, because Jasmine is optimised to handle such promise related issues. Refer [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow).

`Now, I wonder if its as good as using selenium in Java in this scenario.` - IMO it depends on your choice and ease of working with the libraries in hand. If you are able to handle the async behaviour of the app using Selenium with Java, then you should go ahead and pick the same.

Comment: You should be aware `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` is deprecated in the latest Protractor release (6) and is no longer enabled by default. It is recommended to use the async/await syntax for handling promises going forward

Comment: Wasn't aware about this.

Answer (score -1):

The only issue with angular is that it waits for certain response but still the all the elements on the page gets loaded hence the execution fails. But I've created certain methods in selenium that are same as protractor waits. You can use these.

public static void waitUntilAngular5Ready() {
        try {
            Object angular5Check = jsExec.executeScript("return getAllAngularRootElements()[0].attributes['ng-version']");
            if (angular5Check != null) {
                Boolean angularPageLoaded = (Boolean) jsExec.executeScript("return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1");
                System.out.println(angularPageLoaded +" angularPageLoaded");
                if (!angularPageLoaded) {
                    poll(5);

```
                waitForAngular5Load();

                poll(5);
            }
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
    }
}

private static void waitForAngular5Load() {
    String angularReadyScript = "return window.getAllAngularTestabilities().findIndex(x=>!x.isStable()) === -1";
    angularLoads(angularReadyScript);
}

private static void angularLoads(String angularReadyScript) {
    try {
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> angularLoad = driver -> Boolean.valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());

        boolean angularReady = Boolean.valueOf(jsExec.executeScript(angularReadyScript).toString());

        if (!angularReady) {
            jsWait.until(angularLoad);
        }
    } catch (WebDriverException ignored) {
    }
}
```